# using strptime converting string to time but getting garbage

Tags: c++, strptime

I have a problem with using strptime() function in c++.

I found  a piece of code in stackoverflow like below and I want to store string time information on struct tm. Although I should get year information on my tm tm_year variable, I always get a garbage.Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

```
    string  s = dtime;
    struct tm timeDate;
    memset(&timeDate,0,sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime(s.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &timeDate);
    cout<<timeDate.tm_year<<endl; // in the example below it gives me 113
    cout<<timeDate.tm_min<<endl; // it returns garbage 
**string s will be like "2013-12-04 15:03"**
```

Comment: @Kunal it always be YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM like 2013-12-04 15:03

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cout<<timeDate.tm_year<<endl; // in the example below it gives me 113
```

it is supposed to give you value decreased by `1900` so if it gives you `113` it means the year is `2013`. Month will also be decreased by `1`, i.e. if it gives you `1`, it is actually February. Just add these values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    struct tm tm{};
    std::string s("2013-12-04 15:03");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &tm)) {
        int d = tm.tm_mday,
            m = tm.tm_mon + 1,
            y = tm.tm_year + 1900;
        std::cout << y << "-" << m << "-" << d << " "
                  << tm.tm_hour << ":" << tm.tm_min;
    }
}
```

outputs `2013-12-4 15:3`

Comment: Is there any way to block it ? I mean I want to get what it is given as string ? for example if s is "2017-04-15 04:15" I want to store tm_year 2017 tm_month=04 and tm_min=15 ? How could I do that ? @LihO

Comment: got it , only way is making some trick like that. Thanks a lot

Comment: you need to zero-out `struct tm tm` otherwise the result is undefined. :)

Comment: should it be `struct tm tm {};`?

Comment: @junhan The man page for `strptime()` shows an example that initializes the structure with `memset(&tm, 0, sizeof (struct tm));`.

Comment: @Pulseczar No need for `memset` here. With junhan's suggestion the structure is immediately [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) with the compiler generating the code.