# Comparing dates in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at c++ and I was struggling with using date. I thought the ctime library might be helpful but I'm not sure.

For my program, I need to let someone enter the date they joined a club, then I need to compare that with the current date to work out a membership fee.

I also wasn't sure of the best way to take in the date (e.g. enter day/month/year separately or together as a string?).

I couldn't find a simple way of doing this and I would greatly appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't mess with day/month/year. Use seconds after some point in time.

Comment: What command would that involve? Edit: also would that work since some months are different lengths?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

Comment: I'm not using the 2011 version so I don't think that works - there's an error when I try it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c

Comment: @stylersolve _"'m not using the 2011 version"_ Can fallback to `boost::chrono` then.

Comment: This header only date library is being proposed for standardization. https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 3):

You can get the date from the user and parse it into a tm structure using strptime.

For example:

```
tm timeDate;
strptime(input_str.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &timeDate); // define date / time format convenient for you here; this is just an example
```

Then convert to a time_t type:

```
time_t time_input = mktime(&timeDate);
```

Then compare with another time_t (created the same way or by getting the current system time or whatever you need);

```
double timeDiff = difftime(time_input, other_time_t_value);
```

Resources used:

[time tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm)

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776032/date-and-time-manipulation-in-c)

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524720/using-strptime-converting-string-to-time-but-getting-garbage)

Another option might be the Boost datetime library (I don't remember using it myself so I won't do more than refer you) recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501602/c-compare-two-dates?rq=1)

A note to others reading this question: the OP I believe is not using C++11 or later.  If you are, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767430/whats-the-way-to-compare-dates-in-c?rq=1) might be better for you.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to include the time or can I just find the difference in date?

Comment: You can use just the date, I believe.  Just use only the date elements in the format string.

Comment: I assume that I would make them enter the Y, m and d variables? That seems useful thanks.

Comment: The second resource I linked gives an example with just a date in a very simple format. Looks good, but I haven't tried it.  You could :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/997988/3989888

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << ' ' 
         << (now->tm_mon + 1) << ' '
         <<  now->tm_mday
         << endl;

    cout<<"Enter Date YYYY MM DD"<<endl;
    int y,m,d;
    cin>>y;
    cin>>m;
    cin>>d;

    cout<<"Member since: "<<y-now->tm_year-1900<<" years "<<m-now->tm_mon-1<<" months "<<d-now->tm_mday<<" days "<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful but is there a way to combat the negative months/days? Maybe I could use an if statement and sort through them (although I wouldn't know what to do with months of varying lengths).

Answer (score 0):

Seriously now? Please write modern code and use. `std::chrono::duration`.

Something like

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto long_ago =
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point();
  std::chrono::duration<double> diff =
    std::chrono::system_clock::now() - long_ago;
  std::cout << "Seconds since Jan 1 1970: " << diff.count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: #1: Please be respectful of others. #2: the OP commented that he is not using a compiler which supports this.